# Trying to subset two variables in R at once

Tags: r

I am struggling with some code. What I want to do is subset one column of data with an upper bound and a lower bound value. I want to take the first subset Mars Long between two values and then subset Venus long within the first subset.

Here is the code I have.

```
library(readxl)
data <- read_excel("ephim.xlsx")

planets <- data[c(1,8,10)]

colnames(planets) <- c("Dates","Venus Long", "Mars Long")

new <- data.frame(planets)

f<-subset(new,Mars.Long <100) 
g<- subset(f,Venus.Long <100)        


print(g)
```

Comment: So this code had no error. But, the output is not what I am looking for. I want to subset the value of Mars. Long between two numbers. From that subset, I want to further subset based on Venus. Long values, another factor. The code is good, but I am not getting the correct output.

Answer (score 2):

Use a logical operator with your bounds:

```
f <- subset(new, (Mars.Long > lower_bound) & (Mars.Long < upper_bound) )
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. So I tried this. So I did f <- subset(new, (Mars.Long > lower_bound) & (Mars.Long < upper_bound) ) Then g <-subset(f,Venus.Long >lower_bound) & (Venus.Long <upper_bound). I want to subset again from f. The code works, but the output is off.

Comment: Your parenthesis are off for g. it should be: g <-subset(f,(Venus.Long >lower_bound) & (Venus.Long <upper_bound) )

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` function in `dplyr` package. Avoid `subset` function whenever possible for reasons described [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html).

```
library(dplyr)
input_Data <- input_Data %>% filter(Mars.long > lower_bound, 
                                   Mars.Longs < upper_bound, 
                                   Venus.Long < upper_bound_Ven, 
                                   Venus.Long > lower_bound_Ven)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `[`

```
new[with(new, (Mars.long > lower_bound) & (Mars.Longs < upper_bound)),]
```